# How to write particular nodes of XmlDocument in an xml file

Tags: c#

I have an XmlDocument having no. of "Application" nodes. Now I want to write only "Application" nodes in an xml file. I have tried this usin XDocument and its working as shown below but how can i do the same using XmlDocument.

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
doc.Root.Elements("Application").ToList().ForEach(x => sb.Append(x.ToString()));
string xmlNodes = sb.ToString();
File.WriteAllText("file", xmlNodes);`

Comment: actually, I am working on existing application and it uses XmlDocument and I dont want to modify the existing code. So I cant use XDocument. Thats why I am asking for same kind of code using XmlDocument object. I want the code either using linq or via foreach loop if possible

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against mixing XmlDocuments and XDocuments as they're two different approaches to XML DOM management which aren't particularly easy to compose together.

If you want to use Lynx to XML, and who wouldn't ;), I'd recommend focusing on the X____ types; XDocument, XElement, etc.

To that end, you can manually construct the object graph, or if you prefer, you can create an `XDocument` from source XML:

```
var xml = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Applications>
    <Application id='1'>
        <Name>App1</Name>
    </Application>
    <Application id='2'>
        <Name>App2</Name>
    </Application>
    <Application id='3'>
        <Name>App3</Name>
    </Application>
    <Application id='4'>
        <Name>App4</Name>
    </Application>
    <Application id='5'>
        <Name>App5</Name>
    </Application>
</Applications>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

Once you have the XDocument in hand, you can query it with Lync (or chain methods together if you prefer):

```
var appList = (from app in doc.Root.Descendants("Application")
                select app).ToList();
```

The above code selects all XElements named "Application" under the root node. If you onmit to specify the "Application", you will end up with all the nodes too.

With this list of elements, you can now just write out some data about them:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{appList.Count()} Application Elements Found:");
appList.ForEach(app =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"  Application: {app.Attribute("id")}");
});
```

Note, this is using the C# v6 string interpolation feature - I am sure you can figure out how to manually construct the necessary strings if you're using a prior version of C#? ;)

Hope this sets you on your path to what you want?